# emersion/go-imap - Mark message as seen

Tags: go, imap

I'm trying to mark messages as seen using this IMAP protocol implementation but It's not working as intended.

I have a function that prints unseen messages and my intention is that by the end, it mark each message as seen.

```
package main

import (
    "emailmonitor/util"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    serverGmail := util.NewServerGmail()

    serverGmail.Connect()
    serverGmail.Login()
    serverGmail.ListUnseenMessages()

}

//-----------------------------------------

package util

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/mail"
    "net/smtp"

    imap "github.com/emersion/go-imap"
    "github.com/emersion/go-imap/client"
)

type ServerGmail struct {
    user    string
    pass    string
    erro    string
    cliente *client.Client
}

func NewServerGmail() *ServerGmail {
    serverGmail := &ServerGmail{}
    serverGmail.user = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
    serverGmail.pass = "xxxxx"
    serverGmail.erro = ""

    return serverGmail
}

func (serverGmail *ServerGmail) Connect() {
    // Connect to server
    cliente, erro := client.DialTLS("smtp.gmail.com:993", nil)
    if erro != nil {
        serverGmail.erro = erro.Error()
    }
    log.Println("Connected")

    serverGmail.cliente = cliente

}

func (serverGmail *ServerGmail) Login() {
    // Login
    if erro := serverGmail.cliente.Login(serverGmail.user, serverGmail.pass); erro != nil {
        serverGmail.erro = erro.Error()
    }
    log.Println("Logged")

}

func (serverGmail *ServerGmail) setLabelBox(label string) *imap.MailboxStatus {
    mailbox, erro := serverGmail.cliente.Select(label, true)
    if erro != nil {
        serverGmail.erro = erro.Error()
    }
    return mailbox
}

func (serverGmail *ServerGmail) ListUnseenMessages() {
    // set mailbox to INBOX
    serverGmail.setLabelBox("INBOX")
    // criteria to search for unseen messages
    criteria := imap.NewSearchCriteria()
    criteria.WithoutFlags = []string{"\\Seen"}

    uids, err := serverGmail.cliente.UidSearch(criteria)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    seqSet := new(imap.SeqSet)
    seqSet.AddNum(uids...)
    section := &imap.BodySectionName{}
    items := []imap.FetchItem{imap.FetchEnvelope, imap.FetchFlags, imap.FetchInternalDate, section.FetchItem()}
    messages := make(chan *imap.Message)
    go func() {
        if err := serverGmail.cliente.UidFetch(seqSet, items, messages); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    for message := range messages {

        log.Println(message.Uid)

        if message == nil {
            log.Fatal("Server didn't returned message")
        }

        r := message.GetBody(section)
        if r == nil {
            log.Fatal("Server didn't returned message body")
        }

        // Create a new mail reader
        mr, err := mail.CreateReader(r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // Print some info about the message
        header := mr.Header

        if date, err := header.Date(); err == nil {
            log.Println("Date:", date)
        }
        if from, err := header.AddressList("From"); err == nil {
            log.Println("From:", from)
        }
        if to, err := header.AddressList("To"); err == nil {
            log.Println("To:", to)
        }
        if subject, err := header.Subject(); err == nil {
            log.Println("Subject:", subject)
        }

// MARK "SEEN" ------- STARTS HERE  ---------

        seqSet.Clear()
        seqSet.AddNum(message.Uid)
        item := imap.FormatFlagsOp(imap.AddFlags, true)
        flags := []interface{}{imap.SeenFlag}
        erro := serverGmail.cliente.UidStore(seqSet, item, flags, nil)
        if erro != nil {
            panic("error!")
        }

    }

}
```

Link from Documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/emersion/go-imap/client#Client.UidStore
Tried to do something similar to Store example.

What can be done to fix it?

Comment: I don't have access to test it but I see in documentation that https://github.com/emersion/go-imap/blob/db2527e3b3931fbb4b4e650165816f3570f73875/client/cmd_selected.go#L179 that they say, flags works only when `item` equal `FLAGS`.

Comment: @ttomalak I didn't understand what can be wrong.

I also edited the post to have the complete code

Answer (score 0):

modify the following line by changing true to false

mailbox, erro := serverGmail.cliente.Select(label, true)

once you've done this, when the message is fetched (using the UidFetch), it will be automatically marked to "Seen"